# SHOW/HIDE table rows

Tags: jquery

i have this [User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf2eG.png)

Now i Need that row where is "HELLO" need to be hidden at first and when the user check the checkbox the row "HELLO" will be shown and the other where are "Comino and dropdownlists" will be hide.

I tried this code and the first row is hiding but i dont know what to do to hide the second row and show it when checkbox is checked

This is the fist row(not all the code is here becuase it is quite long):

```
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tablecountry">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                    <th>Sunday</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
             <tr class="row2">
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['country']?></td>
```

this is the second row:

```
  <tr type="hidden" id="rowhidden" class="rowhidden">
                    <td >Hello</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

And this is the jquery if made :

```
   <script>
       $("#change").change(function(){
            $("#tablecountry tr.row2").toggle(!this.checked); 
        });
            </script>
```

and the checkbox name :

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
              <input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change"  value="0" > Change All Countries 


        </div>
    </div>
```

Someone can help to switch by these 2 rows. I need to show only 1 row at a time. If checkbox is checked i need to show the second row and if checkox is now shown i need to show the first row.

Comment: Can i do something  when i change the row i change the button too so they will make different things ?  Because when the user check the checkbox i need to change whole column with his change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could toggle hiding and showing of the other row by using the inverse condition `this.checked`, making the change function look like:

```
$("#change").change(function(){
        $("#tablecountry tr.row2").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#tablecountry tr.rowhidden").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

> "HELLO" need to be hidden at first

For this you could trigger the change event in the script. So the first time it is run, the change event is executed.

```
$("#change").change();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DVJex/yx86a321/1/)

[Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/DVJex/yx86a321/2/) - Above fiddle and also 2 buttons, 1 for showing only first row, another for showing only the second row

Comment: THANK YOU ! :D .. im new to jquery sorry for wasting your time

Comment: There is a thing that i can even change the button too so each row ahve different button and make different things ??

Comment: @SigmondGatt Yes you can have multiple buttons which do different things.

Comment: can you make me a fiddle to switch between them like the rows please ?

Comment: @SigmondGatt I have updated the answer with another fiddle, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank bro SuperLike! :)

Comment: But the problem is at first when i go to this page the two buttons appear and than when i uset he checkbox everythign wroks fine..

Comment: @SigmondGatt I think it's better if you ask a new question and clearly explain what you need.